# Display progress bar vue flask

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I display a progress bar in VUE while a process is running in Flask. I believe it must be something similar to this code, but I can't get the function running.

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-progress-circular v-show="isLoading" indeterminate></v-progress-circular>
      <h1 v-if="predictedClass"> {{ myResult }} </h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    data: () => ({
      isLoading: false,
      myResult : ''
    }),
    mounted() {
          axios
          .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/load").then(response => {
            this.isLoading = response.data.load})
          .get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/result").then(response => {
            this.myResult = response.data.result})
        }
}
</script>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/load', methods=['GET'])
def loading_process():                
    return {"load": true}

@app.route('/result', methods=['GET'])
def process():                
    return {"result": "Some result"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use for the endpoint called `load`.  Change `mounted` to:

```js
mounted() {
   this.isLoading = true;
   axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/result").then(response => {
      this.myResult = response.data.result;
      this.isLoading = false;
   })
}
```

Before making the api call set `isLoading` to `true`, and set it back to `false` in the callback.